# HTTP request with web client. Random error with (Verification failed because the other party has closed the transport stream.)

Tags: c#, angularjs, error-handling, umbraco

Hey hello i am working atm with MVC with Umbraco and i am trying to make API call with webclient http protocol.

This is the request i am doing.

```
[HttpPost]
public JObject CheckAuth()
{

    string URI = "https://nedfinity.api.accelo.com/oauth2/v0/token";
    string myParameters = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read(all)";

    var clientId = "this is a secret";
    var clientSecret = "this is a secret";

    var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(clientId + ":" + clientSecret);

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(HtmlResult);
        return json;
    }
}
```

It used to work just fine all the time but out of no where when i was editiing CSS it stopped working. I tryed to reverse all my commits in bitbucket but no fix.
Also when  try to call the api from accelo its working correctly.
This the only feedback i am getting from the server:

```
data
:
Object
ExceptionMessage
:
"Verification failed because the other party has closed the transport stream." 
ExceptionType
:
"System.IO.IOException"
Message
:
"An error has occurred."
StackTrace
:
"   bij System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
↵   bij System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
↵   bij System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
↵   bij System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
↵   bij System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
↵   bij System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
↵   bij System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
↵   bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
↵   bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
↵   bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
↵   bij System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
↵   bij System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
↵   bij System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
↵   bij System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)"
```

Anyone knows what can cause this problem and how to fix it or where to look?

I am thinking my self it has to do with some config settings or network permissions but it is on a localhost and i didn't change anything in this time that could cause this.

P.S. I hope this correct way to ask a question if did something wrong feel free to point me on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try setting the security protocol to the following:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Most API's now use TLS12 as the default protocol.

Let me know how it goes.

PS. You can add this inside your existing method block.

Regards

Craig

Comment: Hey Craig,

Thanks for the responds. Il try it out right away.

Regards Tim

Comment: Hey Craig, It seems to work :D. Thanks a lot for the help. Did this recently change ?

Regards, Tim

Comment: P.S. Also where could i find this got changed? Was it webclient libary or http request protocol or something else ?

Comment: Hi Oldaran, Glad you sorted out your issue.    TLS 1.2 is the latest encryption standard powering SSL. In general, anything that is using TLS standard below TLS 1.2 is considered to be non-secure because these older encryption algorithms are known to be cracked.

Comment: Alright thanks for the info. I still find it weird that it stopped working out of no where since i am working on SSL all the time.

Comment: @Oldaran no problem! Maybe they have done some updates recently to their API's, you could try checking out their site, blog OR Twitter account for more information potentially. Good luck!